# What does the ruby ? method do?

Tags: ruby

I ran across a code snippet today that used the `?` operator to quote the next character. I have no idea where the documentation is for this method and really no idea what it's actually doing.

I've looked at the ruby docs, but haven't found it.

```rb
?1
```

`=> "1"`

```rb
?1"23abc"
```

`=> "123abc"`

Answer (score 4):

`?` is not a method in this case but rather a parsable syntax. `?` is a character literal in this context

[Docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html) Excerpt:

> There is also a character literal notation to represent single character strings, which syntax is a question mark (?) followed by a single character or escape sequence that corresponds to a single codepoint in the script encoding:

```
?a       #=> "a"
?abc     #=> SyntaxError
?\n      #=> "\n"
?\s      #=> " "
?\\      #=> "\\"
?\u{41}  #=> "A"
?\C-a    #=> "\x01"
?\M-a    #=> "\xE1"
?\M-\C-a #=> "\x81"
?\C-\M-a #=> "\x81", same as above
?あ      #=> "あ"
```

You have also found another fun little mechanism of the parser which is 2 Strings can be concatenated together by simply placing them side by side (with or without white space). e.g.

```
"1" "234" 
#=> "1234"
"1""234"
#=> "1234"
```

Comment: I actually found that in ruby 1.8 and prior, this returns the Ascii number.
```ruby
:001 > ?1
=> 49
```

Good to know about the string concatenation, that's the first I've heard of that.

Comment: @AndrewMerritt I sincerely hope you are not using 1.8 or really anything less than 2.3 (EOL 2019-03-31) but yes technically speaking < 1.9 returned the ASCII number

Comment: Haha, no I'm using 2.5.x in my projects. Just found it to be an interesting tidbit. Apparently I missed the previous question my search, which also shows that same answer.